# Is this the correct use of "mappedBy" in a @OneToOne relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a person class with its basic fields such as name,age etc...and i want to create a seperate table for the car-details of each person,

so i implemented a `@OneToOne` relationship in this manner:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class person {

@OneToOne(mappedBy="person", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
 private CarDetails carDetails ;

//more fields and getters and setters and of course @Id.....
}
```

and another entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAR_DETAILS")
public class CarDetails {

 @Id
 @Column(name= "READER_ID")
 @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")  
 @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="Person"))  
 private long readerId;

 @OneToOne  
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
 private Person person;

//more fields and getters and setters
}
```

everything works fine but i am not sure that this is the right use of "mappedBy".
I read about it somewhat and i came across my kind of implementation but also others so i am a little confused.

could someone elaborate if this is the correct use of "mappedBy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use the old fashion mode

```
@OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, optional = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "person")
@Getter
@Setter
private CarDetails carDetails; 


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")//You will need to create foreign key
@Getter
@Setter
private Person person;
```

Comment: by "parcel" you mean person, right? also, what is the reason you are recommending this and not the above?